# object.style['background'] not working in Mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to read background property of object , following code i have tried in Chrome and it is working perfect but in Mozilla obj.style['background'] doesn't return anything . how to fetch background style property in mozilla??

```
function flipIt(obj)

{
origImg =  obj.style['background'].split(")")[0];
 origImg = origImg.substring(origImg.length-5).split(".")[0];
```

Answer (score 4):

`obj.style['background']` is not really reliable, you should always use

```
var allStyles = getComputedStyle(obj)
allStyles.background
```

instead. This works in all modern browsers<sup>*</sup>. It returns the actually used values (final values for that element after all computations are done) for that element. However, note the following:

1) does not return correct values for `:visited` to prevent the [history leak exploit](http://blog.mozilla.org/security/2010/03/31/plugging-the-css-history-leak/)
2) is inconsistent with CSS transitions

<sup>*: sadly, only IE9+</sup>